# Java EventQueue. Why should everything be in invokelater method?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

in the book that i'm reading, every example of GUI with multithreading has something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            JFrame frame = new SomeKindOfFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

(i mean EventQueue). but isn't the code automatically executed in the main (EDT) thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Desktop GUI applications usually work in this way. There is one thread for gui and one or several threads for rest of application.  Using `EventQueue` you specify what GUI thread should do from other threads.

Comment: Apparently in swing this is called the "single thread rule".  Swing events are proccesed from the event thread which takes these little `Runnable()` instances and runs them.

Comment: @Warren P, totally agree. I just tried to explain this in the easiest way. BTW, thanks for grammar corrections.

Answer (score 15):

The main thread isn't the same as the EDT. If you add `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()` you'll see it print out `main` within `main()` and `AWT-EventQueue-0` when within the `run()` method of the `Runnable`.

Here is [a discussion of the history of the single threaded rule in Swing](https://bitguru.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/will-the-real-swing-single-threading-rule-please-stand-up/) that might help make things clearer.